# Does $\|Ax\|=\|Bx\| \enspace \forall x\in D(A)=D(B)$ imply $\langle Ax,Ay \rangle = \langle Bx,By \rangle$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I used this with additional assumption of A and B being closed in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923063/let-a-and-b-closed-operators-show-ax-bx-for-all-x-in-da-db). But i would like to see the proof or some counter-examples

Comment: Use the polarisation identity

Comment: @s.harp : So we define sesqulinear product $s(f,g):D(A)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $s(f,g)=\langle Af,Ag \rangle$ then we define quadratic form $q(f)=s(f,f)$from this .Noticing it will be equal to $q_b(f)=\langle Bx,Bx \rangle$ now by polarization we obtain $s_b(f,g)$ but these 2 are equal therefore done . ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the sesquilinear form is also symmetric (in the way that sequilinear forms can be symmetric) which is necessary for the correspondence to "quadratic" forms to be invertible (remember $q(\lambda f) = |\lambda|^2 q(f)$ and not $\lambda^2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If $\|Az\|=\|Bz\|$ for all $z\in D(A)$ (where $X$ is a space with scalar product $(.,.)$ - assumed from the question) then we can put $z=x-y$ and we get $\|Az\|^2=\|Ax\|^2-2(Ax,Ay)+\|Ay\|^2=\|Bx\|^2-2(Bx,By)+\|By\|^2=\|Bz\|^2$. Using our assumption again (i.e. $\|Ax\|=\|Bx\|$ and $\|Ay\|=\|By\|$), we arrive to $(Ax,Ay)=(Bx,By)$ for every $x,y\in D(A)$.

Comment: In this proof you assume that the background is a _real_ Hilbert space. The polarisation identity for complex Hilbert spaces is different.

Comment: yes, in complex H-space it is different